# MiniTest - route not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I have a POST model, controller, and view and I'm currently creating its test suite to make sure everything is properly tested. I'm creating the integration test now and always seem to get the same error that says the ID is missing when it runs the "edits a post successfully" test.

I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong.  The error message says that an :id key is missing, but shouldn't one automatically be created when a new post is created?  What am I doing wrong?

**VERSIONS:**
Ruby: 2.1.2
Rails: 4.2.1

**INTEGRATION TEST**

```
require 'test_helper'

class PostsCrudTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def setup
    @post = { title: "This is the title",
               content: "Detailed comment."*10,
               phone: 9991118888,
               email: "email@h_list.com",
               user_id: users(:spiderman).id }
  end

  test "creates a new post successfully" do 
    get new_post_path
    assert_template 'posts/new'
    assert_difference 'Post.count', 1 do 
      post posts_path, post: @post
    end
    assert_template 'posts/show'
  end

  test "fails to create a new post with inaccurate info" do 
    get new_post_path
    assert_no_difference 'Post.count' do 
      post posts_path, post: { title: "", content: "", phone: 1111, email: 00 }
    end
    assert_template 'posts/new'
  end

  test "shows a new post correctly" do 
    get new_post_path
    post posts_path, post: @post
    assert_template 'posts/show'
    assert_equal 'Your new posting was created.', flash[:success]
    assert_select 'h2', @post[:title]
    assert_select 'h2+p', @post[:content]
  end

  test "edits a post successfully" do 
    get new_post_path
    post posts_url, post: @post
    assert_template 'posts/show'

    get edit_post_path, post: @post
    # assert_select '.edit_post' do 
      assert_select 'textarea', @post[:content]
    # end
  end


end
```

**TEST RESULTS**

```
$ rake test:integration
Run options: --seed 35902

# Running:

...E

Finished in 0.310827s, 12.8689 runs/s, 32.1722 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
PostsCrudTest#test_edits_a_post_successfully:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts"} missing required keys: [:id]
test/integration/posts_crud_test.rb:44:in `block in <class:PostsCrudTest>'

4 runs, 10 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

**RELATED ROUTES:**

```
               posts GET    /posts(.:format)               posts#index
                     POST   /posts(.:format)               posts#create
            new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)           posts#new
           edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)      posts#edit
                post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#show
                     PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                     PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#update
                     DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)           posts#destroy
```

**NOTE:** Everything seems to be working well on the actual site.  It's just the test suite that's giving me this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The error message says that an :id key is missing

Yes, because you're doing two steps:

1. You create a new post by using the @post hash. I presume the post is created on the server, which typically means the post is created in the database, and a new id is created.
2. You try to edit the @post hash, which doesn't have any id. This is why you're getting the error message.

There are a variety of options to solve this.

Option 1 is easy: create the post directly in code, not using the new_post_path.

Example:

```
test "edits a post successfully" do 
  p = Post.create(@post)  # or whatever options you want
  get edit_post_path, post: p.id
  ...
```

Option 2 is advanced: create the post as you are doing, and make your server return the id of the newly-created post. You can put it in the HTTP response if you want, or put it in something more structural such as a JSON response.